# AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, azure-active-directory, logout

i am having asp.net web application. i am migrating this application to azure and implementing Azure AD Authentication. AD authentication and Approle based authorization are working as expected. i am facing issue while signing-out from Application.

[AAD-Sign-out-response-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uzhd.png)

referred [msdn-site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98350e5d-07cf-4d5e-bbba-9fd707cb0107/aadsts90056-this-endpoint-only-accepts-post-requests-received-a-get-request?forum=WindowsAzureAD) tried with these settings as well, still i am getting same issue.

need help on resolving this issue!! thanks!!

my signout method in account controller has following

```
public void SignOut()
    {

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
        .Authentication

        .SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
 
    }
```

Startup.cs configauth as belows

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {


        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);


        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    NameClaimType = "upn",
                    RoleClaimType = "roles",    // The claim in the Jwt token where App roles are provided.
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    //
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    //
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }

            });

        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);           
        

    }
```

web.config with AD configuration details as follows

```
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"/>
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"/>
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}"/>
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logoutsession/"/>
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/"/>
```

Comment: COuld you please provide your code?

Comment: @JimXu: thanks for helping...i have updated code and config details. please let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to re-create your problem, and if you configured the logouturl in the portal like I did, you can try deleting it and then running the program.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried removing logout url and added application url. its working as expected. Thank you!!

Comment: @PMCKarur 

If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.